# Is there some functionality in/for Delphi that converts a string with html named and numbered entities to unicode text?

Tags: html, delphi, unicode, entities

I read data from a mysql database that has is filled by php scripts. All special characters are converted to named or numbered html entities (for example & a m p ; & # 2 8 6 ;).
I know of no way to convert these characters back to the original ones in Delphi as unicode strings. Did anyone ever find or even create such a function? This would be very helpful to me. Thanks!
Marc

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Delphi 2007 there is a unit called **HTTPApp.pas** (in [Delphi Folder]\Source\Win32\Internet) that has the functions **HTMLEncode** and **HTMLDecode**. They might be worth a look.

Comment: Right, this really looks interesting.
I will test this unit later on, but as far as i can see this seems to solve the question.
Thanks!

Comment: `HTTPApp/HTMLDecode( )` has been deprecated.  The new unit and method are `System.NetEncoding/TNetEncoding.HTML.Decode( )`.