# HTML special character conversion in Delphi

Tags: html, delphi, freepascal, character-encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [delphi html decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657105/delphi-html-decode)

Does anybody know where to find a Delphi or Freepascal library to decode special characters in HTML, encoded in HTML Entity(decimal, hex or name)?

Ex. &#xCO; converts into À

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657105/delphi-html-decode

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1097244/576719) answer to the question `Is there some functionality in/for Delphi that converts a string with html named and numbered entities to unicode text?` of any use ?